# how to capture the error message of a given errorlevel and put it in a log file using

Tags: batch-file

let's say I have this:

```
C:\Users\test folder>dir ren asdf.txt test.txt >> log.txt
File Not Found

C:\Users\mary.angela.c.neri\Desktop\test folder>echo %errorlevel% >> log.txt

C:\Users\mary.angela.c.neri\Desktop\test folder>%errorlevel%
'9009' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I searched the meaning of errorlevel 9009 and it says 'File not found' so I wanted to display that in my log file what should I do?

Comment: There is no `ErrorTextOfCode(%errorlevel%)` command - Windows uses numeric error codes specifically _because_ they don't have to store text that way.

Comment: Are you saying you want to add `file not found` to the log file? if so then redirect stderr to the logfile, instead of stdout. `dir ren asdf.txt test.txt 2> log.txt` or both stderr and stdout `dir ren asdf.txt test.txt > log.txt 2>&1`

Comment: hello yes this is exactly what i want to do, but will this be possible with their errorlevel value in log file??

like: (9009 = file not found) just to show both??

Comment: with `9009`, `cmd` actually means "there is no such command or file". Note that errorlevels are not defined anywhere. Basically, each programmer is free to use any number they want. *Usually* (by convention), zero means "success" and any non-zero numbers mean "failure", but some programmers have different mindsets. Each try for a general "translation table" for errorlevels to text is doomed from the start.